# When filtering search results by date, should time zone be crtieria for the date?

Tags: datetime, localization, usability

We have a website that has a large number of events that have dates and times created by admins.  Admins choose a time zone for each date time entered, and they are stored in UTC time.  We are trying to support a global audience, and be completely localized in terms of dates.

We have a search page, that allows dates to be entered as search criteria.

So users could say, show me all events between "12:01 AM July-1-2011" and "11:59 PM July 10-2011".

I'm trying to figure out what the best approach is to determining what time zone to consider the date filter criteria in.

1. Force end users to select a time zone when creating a date filters.  This is cumbersome, and our designers our pushing back.  It is what I would prefer.
2. Assume the the entered dates are in the users "preferred" time zone, which is set upon logging in.
3. Store times in Local time, without converting to UTC.  This way the end users are searching in the admin created date.  I hate this idea, i need help explaining why this is bad.

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Second option is possible solution to your problem. And it is probably the best.

Possibly you could get current time zone offset from web browser (with JavaScript) but the problem is, there are certain time zones that currently have the same offset but Daylight Saving Time switches on different dates, therefore search result would be inaccurate. By having User to choose his/her prefer time zone and storing that information in the profile, you could always present correct dates and times, as well as use this information for searching. However, I would add an information near search box, so that end User would know what time zone this refers to (with JavaScript that would be obvious: the current one, with profile User might forgot).
BTW. Time zone information is best to show as "UTC+02:00 (Warsaw, Zagreb, Skopje)" instead "Central European Time"...

As for other options:
1. Too much clicking. As well as "don't make me think, I want to have it in my local time zone, isn't that obvious?".
3. Local times will not be comparable against each other. You will soon end up with two different dates referring to the same point in time (at least in terms of the numbers). Really bad idea.